# Cannot log into mysql admin after upgrade: [ERROR] unknown variable 'log_bin_trust_function_creators=1'

Tags: mysql

I have mysql running on an aws EC2 node. After upgrading to mysql8 I can no longer access the admin via the command line.

`sudo mysql` or `mysql -u user -p password` both give me:

```
mysql: [ERROR] unknown variable 'log_bin_trust_function_creators=1'.
```

I have commented out any references to `log_bin_trust_function_creators` (underscores or dashes) in the various cnf files but the issue persists. Can anyone shed any light on this?

Comment: Is the option in the correct group (`[mysqld]`) in your cnf files?

Comment: Thanks for your input, @user1191247. Yes it was in the correct group. However, I found the culprit: the option was specified in several places, including `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysql.cnf`, where it had been overlooked. Updated in all configuration files, I can now log in as normal.

Comment: `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysql.cnf` usually contains just a `[mysql]` section, which applies to the MySQL command line client. The fact that you received this error when trying to run the `mysql` client confirms that its was in either a `[mysql]` or `[client]` group in the option file - [mysql Client Options](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-command-options.html#:~:text=in%20the%20%5Bmysql%5D%20and%20%5Bclient%5D%20groups%20of%20an%20option%20file).

Answer (score 0):

The issue was as follows:

the option was specified in several different mysql configuration files, one of which was overlooked.

Always remember to scan every folder that may contain configuration files, and check the contents of every file carefully.

Possible locations/filenames include:

```
/etc/my.cnf
/etc/mysql/my.cnf
$MYSQL_HOME/my.cnf
[datadir]/my.cnf
~/.my.cnf
/etc/alternatives/my.cnf
/etc/mysql/mysql.cnf
client.cnf
mysql-server.cnf
/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysql.cnf
```